# Need help on MCU 8051 (Logical Op.)

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

```
MAIN: MOV C,P1.6
      ANL C,P1.5
      ANL C,P1.4
      CPL C
      MOV P1.7,C
      JMP MAIN
```

Above is for showing the NAND operation with 3 inputs, by using 3 buttons and the output is shown by an LED. It's not working according to the truth table.

Used Port 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 for the input, and 1.7 for the output.

Comment: What results are you actually getting? Which conditions of the inputs give incorrect output and what are they?

Comment: The output only lit = 1 when the input is all 0. If any of input is 1, then the output will be 0.

Comment: Your code looks correct. The behavior you're seeing, though, acts like a NOR (as if you had `ORL` instead of `ANL`). But I'm assuming that the port reads as you show them work as expected. If a button is pressed, are you sure that reading `P1.x` just yields a 1?

Comment: It seems to yield 1 on all bit location.. that's weird lol

Comment: what's p1.4 - p1.6's states, when they're pressed? 0 or 1 ?

Comment: 1 in all bit locations is fine as long as it's consistent. Is it 1 in all locations if pressed and 0 in all locations if not pressed? Or what is it? That's important!

Comment: @Tommylee2k it states 1 all the time

Comment: @lurker currently using MCU 8051 IDE, in the P1 section it shows all 1

Comment: But is it all 1 if the button is pressed, and 0 if the button is not pressed?

Comment: @lurker nope it shows 1 whether pressed or not

Comment: That sounds like a problem. How are you supposed to distinguish pressed versus not pressed?

Comment: @lurker woot it solved, the solution is kinda weird, i've used `ORL` instead, and it's working same as truth table hahaha thanks helping c:

Comment: Are you sure you were after NAND behavior and not AND behavior? If you take NEG(A OR B OR C) that's the same as (NEG A) AND (NEG B) AND (NEG C) which isn't a NAND, (which would be NEG(A AND B AND C), or same as (NEG A) OR (NEG B) OR (NEG C)).

Comment: @lurker I'm sure i'm after NAND behaviour

Comment: I'm never happy just getting something to spit out what looks like the right answer. I like to know *why* it works. In this case, it's not making much sense.